# Prove $\lim\limits_{x\to-2} (x^2 - 1) = 3$

Tags: calculus

Prove $$\lim_{x\to-2} (x^2 - 1) = 3$$

Using the precise definition of a limit with epsilon and delta using $C$ and absolute values. Calculus concepts and contexts section 2.4 problem 31. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Note the hilarity of this. The OP is quoting a particular problem in a particular section in a textbook. Obviously, this is just a copied homework problem. Why was there an upvote for it?

Comment: Hint: $|x^2 - 4| = |x - 2||x + 2|$

Comment: Hint: Read *Calculus Concepts and Contexts*, §2.4.

Comment: @AhaanRungta, I upvoted for providing a reference, which is something that is rarely done on the site.  Quoting a problem together with its source is exactly the kind of thing that increases the value of a Q-A site.  Among other benefits, it gives evidence that the question is correct, makes answers locatable from a search engine, and helps to identify related answers already on the site.  The idea that a "copied homework problem" is a bad thing is an unjustified prejudice on MSE, and I predict that over time it will fade as  homework-based evaluation is phased out.

Answer (score 4):

Show that $\forall$ $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists \delta_\epsilon > 0$ such that $|x^2 - 1 - 3| < \epsilon$ whenever $0 < |x + 2| < \delta_\epsilon$

Take any $\epsilon > 0$

$|x^2 - 1 - 3| = |x^2 - 4| = |(x - 2)(x + 2)|$
(Difference of Two Squares)

$|(x - 2)(x + 2)| = |x + 2||x - 2|$

Need to find a bound for $|x - 2|$

Take for instance, $|x + 2| < 1$

$|x - 2| = |x + 2 - 2 - 2|$ 
(This does not change anything since $2 - 2 =0$)

Using the Triangle Inequality $|x + y| \le |x| + |y|$

$|x + 2 - 2 - 2| \le |x + 2| + |-4| < 1 + 4 = 5$

Therfore, $|x - 2||x + 2| < 5|x + 2| < \epsilon$

$\implies |x + 2| < \frac{\epsilon}{5}$

Take $\delta_\epsilon = \min \lbrace{1, \frac{\epsilon}{5}}\rbrace$ and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $|x^2-1-3|=|x-2||x+2|$.  Assume that $\delta < 1$, what does this give you?